# In derivation of capillary rise we take the upwards pressure as $2T/r$. How?

Tags: surface-tension, capillary-action

In the derivation of capillary rise, we take excess pressure due to surface tension in upward direction as equal to $2T/r$.

Can some one please explain how does this come about?

Comment: Refer to Young-Laplace equation. The answers given are correct but in think this is more fundamental

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivation can be thought of as this:

Let,

- Radius of Capillary be $r$
- Density of the liquid $\rho$
- Height of the liquid be $h$
- Surface Tension of Liquid be $T$
- Contact angle $\theta$

Weight of liquid inside capillary = Volume * Density * $g$
$$=\pi r^2 h \rho g$$Which is the downward force, and the force that is balancing this is the force due to Surface tension.

Now, Surface tension is defined as the Force acting on a line which is on the surface. In this case the surface tension is acting on the circumference.

Hence, total force upwards: component of Surface Tension upwards * length of the line it acts on
$$T\cos\theta (2\pi r)$$
The $\sin\theta$ components gets cancelled as it is radially outward throughout the circumference.

Equating the forces we get:
$$\pi r^2 h \rho g = T\cos\theta (2\pi r)$$ 
$$\implies h = \frac{2T\cos\theta}{r\rho g}$$

Note: In cases of some liquids the $\theta$ is very close to $0$ degrees and hence the cos$\theta$ term can be taken as $1$.

Answer (score -1):

We know that $p=dgh$, where $d=$ density, $g=$ acceleration due to gravity, $h=$ height. Therefore, from the above equation $p=2T/r$ where $\cos \theta =1$.